Enable OEM install on rootfs Kubuntu
I didn't find answer to my question so I'll post it here. I'm working on Kubuntu rootfs and I want to enable OEM install on first boot because standardized image will be distributed to multiple devices. How can I achieve that?
Thanks,
Stan

Should be the same as in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386806/what-is-oem-installation-regarding-linux-distributions

@ChanganAuto no it's not the same. I am working with arm64 rootfs filesystem and I want to create what is mentioned in that article. I'm not installing so to speak Ubuntu, I'm creating bootable system for arm64 SBC (single board computer) and I want users to be able to create their own username, hostname etc.
So, basically I want to know how I can enable OEM install on created rootfs using CLI commands

If the aforementioned package exists for your hardware architecture then yes, it's exactly the same: Install it, run it and in the next boot users will be asked to set username, password, etc. For additional setup like e.g. specific network configuration you may consider to add a script for that.

#!/bin/bash

ROOTFS="/mnt/rootfs"

# Ensure the necessary filesystems are mounted
sudo mount --bind /dev $ROOTFS/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys $ROOTFS/sys
sudo mount --bind /proc $ROOTFS/proc

# Chroot into the root filesystem
sudo chroot $ROOTFS <<EOF
apt update
apt install -y oem-config oem-config-gtk
echo 'd-i oem-config/enable boolean true' > /etc/oem-config.conf
ln -s /usr/sbin/oem-config-firstboot /etc/rc2.d/S99oem-config-firstboot

cat <<EOL > /etc/systemd/system/oem-config.service
[Unit]
Description=OEM Configuration
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/oem-config-firstboot
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOL

ln -s /etc/systemd/system/oem-config.service /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/oem-config.service
EOF

# Clean up and exit chroot
sudo umount $ROOTFS/dev
sudo umount $ROOTFS/sys
sudo umount $ROOTFS/proc

echo "OEM setup is enabled on the root filesystem."


Thanks, that's what I was looking for :)
